# When adding hyperlinks using the markup brackets [[ - can I make the link open in a new tab?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink

I'm adding a huge amount of hyperlink content to an Office 365 SharePoint page that I paste in with the following format:

```
[[ link name #1 | www.link1.com]]
[[ link name #2 | www.link2.com]]
[[ link name #3 | www.link3.com]]
```

If I create the hyperlinks manually I have the option to have the link `"open in a new tab"` is there way to have these links (in markup format) open in new tabs without manually editing each link?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid it is not possible in SharePoint Online Markdown web part.

I’ve read a few posts suggesting that we can use plain HTML in Markdown to achieve this requirement. (One example here: [Can I create links with 'target=“_blank”' in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown)) However, this feature is not supported by [**Marked**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-markdown-web-part-6d73c06d-2877-4bc9-988b-f2896016c50b), which is the power engine for Markdown web part.

There is a post in SharePoint UserVoice suggesting the same idea:
[markdown html support](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/40192906-markdown-html-support)